# Get Formik state from the parent component

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am building a package to generate forms. It exports a component that takes a schema to create the form fields. I am using Formik to manage the form state.

I want to get access to the form state from the parent/consuming component but I don't know how to go about it.

Stripped out code sample:

```js
// Child/consumable component

import { Formik, Form as FormikForm } from "formik";

export function DynamicForm(props) {
  return (
    <Formik {...props}>
      <FormikForm
        className="needs-validation"
        noValidate=""
        onChange={props.handleChange}
      >
        {/* a loop to generate the form fields using the schema */}
        {props.children}
      </FormikForm>
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

```js
// Parent component

import { DynamicForm } from '....';

// >>> I would like to have a variable here that contains the form's state <<<

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DynamicForm
        enableReinitialize
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        formSchema={formSchema}
        handleChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.name, e.target.value)}
      >
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </DynamicForm>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you